# Need solution to solve this error Exception:Org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:MessageBodyWriter

Tags: java, ant

I have created a java program to consume rest API object using javax.ws.rs.client .It is working very fine.but when i create jar file and try to run jar file it trove  Exception that is "Exception:Org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:MessageBodyWriter ...."

I have tried to add all the jar files which i used in build.xml so that it is available and packed in jar file which will be build

```
package gui;

import com.bean.BulkUserBean;
import javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.bean.ImageBean;
import com.bean.UserBean;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
//import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 *
 * @author SPEED
 */
public class NewJerseyClient {

    private WebTarget webTarget;
    private Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.42:8080/ImageUpload/control";
//  private static final String BASE_URL = "http://35.200.234.184/ImageUpload/control";

    public NewJerseyClient() {

        System.out.println("Hello --");
        /* client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
         webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI);

         */ System.out.println("Hello");
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    }

    public UserBean getUser(String id) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(BASE_URL).path("user").path(id);

        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

        UserBean user = response.readEntity(UserBean.class);

        System.out.println(response.getStatus());
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        return user;
    }

    public UserBean[] getUser() throws ClientErrorException {
        System.out.println("Url " + BASE_URL);
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(BASE_URL).path("user");
        System.out.println("Url " + BASE_URL);

        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

        UserBean[] user = response.readEntity(UserBean[].class);

        System.out.println(response.getStatus());
        return user;
    }

    public String translate() throws ClientErrorException {
        return webTarget.path("sample").request().post(null, String.class);
    }

    public BulkUserBean getUserList(int offset, int limit) throws ClientErrorException {
        System.out.println("Url " + BASE_URL);
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(BASE_URL).path("userList");
        System.out.println("Url " + BASE_URL);
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

//Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
//Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(new BulkUserBean(offset, limit), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        BulkUserBean b = new BulkUserBean();
        b.setOffset(offset);
        b.setLimit(limit);

        Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(b, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        BulkUserBean user = response.readEntity(BulkUserBean.class);
        return user;
    }

}
```

This i added in build.xml

```
    <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/hsqldb.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/icepdf-core-6.2.2.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/icepdf-viewer-6.2.2.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/itextpdf-5.5.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jackcess-2.1.11.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jakarta.json.bind-api-1.0.1.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jakarta.json-1.1.5.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.2.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.2.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/javafx-ui-common.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-client.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-common.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-container-servlet.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-container-servlet-core.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-hk2.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-media-jaxb.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-media-json-binding.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />   
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-media-sse.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />   
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jersey-server.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />   
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/jpedal_lgpl.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />  
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/org.apache.commons.io.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />       
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />   
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" /> 
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/yasson-1.0.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />        
    <zipfileset src="dist/lib/ucanaccess-4.0.4.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
```

Comment: Do I see this right? You take all these jar files and merge them together? The problem with this is that there might be overlapping classes and that could be the source of your ``NotFound`` problem.
You should think about using your jar file only for your code and only referencing the other jar files. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: thanks for the reply but i don't know how to do this in netbeans javaproject .i have same doubt of overlapping classes but don't know how to solve it in net beans

Comment: You should have a look at the Netbeans documentation then? https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html